# Como pongo a la escucha de un evento los botones de volumen de android?

Tags: java, android-studio

Por ejemplo, digamos que en `MainActivity.class` tengo un `TextView` que si presionamos la tecla de volumen + automáticamente en el `TextView` mostrará un 1 y si seguimos presionando la tecla de volumen + se ira incrementado, pasara lo contrario con el boton de volumen -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proba con lo siguiente

```
 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

//Obtenemos el click del boton de volumen + y -

    @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            int cont = 0;
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                          cont++;
                         //si queres ajustar el volumen
                        //audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                     textView.setText("Volumen: "+cont);
                    }
                    return true;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        cont--;
//audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

                    textView.setText("Volumen: "+cont);
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        }
```

Con eso generamos una variable entera que sea contador , en este caso cont.

Cuando apretamos el boton de subir volumen incrementamos el contador y lo pasamos al `TextView`, cuando bajamos el volumen ocurre lo contrario. Deje comentada las lineas que podes usar para ajustar el volumen

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, gracias

Comment: bro en el setText me da error sabes a que se debe

Comment: que error te da